# How can I install yum rpm packages without internet connection?

Tags: installation, rpm, yum, internet-connection

This question has been asked before but mine is a bit different.

I want to install a bunch of rpm packages using sudo yum. I do not have internet connection on the machine I want to install them on. These packages also do not exist on any machine in the network.

Is there a way I can install them without internet connectivity and with them not anywhere on any machine in the network (so cannot use --downloadonly option) ?

Answer (score 7):

if you have the RPM files on your local machine or any machine (not from network but you literally downloaded the `.rpm` files) then you can run

```
yum localinstall <path to rpm file>
```

you can also do

```
rpm -ivh <rpm file>
```

Comment: I do not have them on any machine that I can connect to. Lets suppose I want to do this - sudo yum -y -q install nettle

Comment: you can download it to a thumb drive and unload?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can install them without internet connectivity and
>   with them not anywhere on any machine in the network

No, that is called an [air gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)). You need to get the RPMs on the machine or network to have them installed.